# How to upload images to Wordpress programatically but prevent them showing up in Media Library?

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I'm having a form with two image fields () and I've created a function that uploads the file really nice and neat. All of the files (only images allowed) are shown in Media Library.

But now I need them not to be visible in Media Library.

This is the function I use, and I even had wp_insert_attachment in it and now have it commented, hoping that it will be enough.

The images still show up in Media.

```
 function insertImage ($file){

        $wordpress_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $i = 1; // number of tries when the file with the same name is already exists

        $upload_dir_custom = $wordpress_upload_dir['basedir']."/custom-folder";
        if (!file_exists($upload_dir_custom)) {
            mkdir( $upload_dir_custom,0755,true) ;

        }

        $new_file_path = $upload_dir_custom;
        $new_file_mime = mime_content_type( $file['tmp_name'] );

        if( empty( $file ) )
            die( 'File is not selected.' );
        if( $file['error'] )
            die( $file['error'] );
        if( $file['size'] > wp_max_upload_size() )
            die( 'Image is too large!.' );
        if( !in_array( $new_file_mime, get_allowed_mime_types() ) )
            die( 'WordPress doesn\'t allow this type of uploads.' );
        while( file_exists( $new_file_path ) ) {
            $i++;
            if($i>1){
                $new_file_path = $wordpress_upload_dir['basedir'] . '/sponsor-info/' . $i . '_' .$file['name'];
            }else{
                $new_file_path = $wordpress_upload_dir['basedir'] . '/sponsor-info/'.$file['name'];

            }
        }
        if( move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], $new_file_path ) ) {

            $image_url = $wordpress_upload_dir['url'] . '/sponsor-info/' . basename( $new_file_path);
            return  $image_url;

        }

    }
```